# Kafka Connect Avro Console Consumer Hanging

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am following @RobinMoffat 's "Simplest Useful.." tutorial for Kafka Connect and trying to connect to my own MySQL database. I load the config file and then check the status getting this:

```
    {
 "name": "mysql-9202_Voltage",
 "config": {
   "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
   "tasks.max": "10",
   "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://AWS_mysql_conection_string:3306?user=user&password=pw",
   "table.whitelist": "`9202-WiFi_Voltage`",
   "mode": "timestamp",
   "timestamp.column.name": "TmStamp",
   "topic.prefix": "FT-9202V",
   "name": "mysql-9202_Voltage"
 },
 "tasks": [],
 "type": null
}

I then check the status and get: 
{
 "name": "mysql-9202_Voltage",
 "connector": {
   "state": "RUNNING",
   "worker_id": "192.168.1.209:8083"
 },
 "tasks": [],
 "type": "source"
}
```

I then run:

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer \
> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
> --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
> --property print.key=true \
> --from-beginning \
> --topic FT-9202V
```

and it just hangs there.  I have tried this locally on my Mac and also in the cloud on Linux. Same exact issue. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the Connect logs after posting the config, do you see activity?

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I ask how I would look at the logs. Sorry, I'm a newb! Or are you just saying when I load the config file does anything happen in the terminal?

Comment: You can run `confluent logs connect`, I believe if that's how you started Connect.